# Apply fundamental theorem with singularity

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I am trying to compute $$\int_{S_1^+(0)}\left(1 - \frac{1}{z^2}\right)e^{z + 1/z}dz$$ where $S_1^+(0)$ is the unit circle at $z= 0$.
This function clearly has an anti-derivative in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and our closed path is in the domain, therefore is it correct to say that this integral is zero by the fundamental theorem, the singularity at zero is throwing me off a bit.

Comment: No it does not, since the logarithm is not single-valued on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @Nik The fact that the logarithm is not globally defined is the very "heart" of complex analysis.  $\frac{1}{z}$ has an antiderivative (a "branch of the logarithm") on any open set which **does not** contain a closed loop around the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals only requires an antiderivative in a neighborhood of the path.  The singularity at the origin is irrelevant.

There are a lot of theorems as you begin to learn complex analysis which sound similar.  You will need to learn to distinguish.

**The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTOC) for Line Integrals** says that if $f$ is continuous on an open set $\Omega$ (which might not be simply connected) and there is an $F$ such that $F' = f$ then for any path $\gamma:[0,1] \to \Omega$ we have

$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\textrm{ d}z = F(\gamma(1)) - F(\gamma(0))
$$

This is what you are applying here.

The FTOC also implies that $\int_{C(0,1)} \frac{1}{z^2} \textrm{ d}z = 0$ for instance.

The FTOC does not allow us to talk about  $\int_{C(0,1)} \frac{1}{z} \textrm{ d}z$ since $\frac{1}{z}$ has no globally defined antiderivative.  In fact, the FTOC allows us to prove that:  if it did the integral would have to be zero, but we can explicitly compute that it is not zero.  Hence there can be no global antiderivative.

A theorem which doesn't have a standard name but which I might call the **converse of the FTOC** is that if $f$ is continuous on an open set $\Omega$ (which might not be simply connected) and the integral is path independent, which means that for any $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 : [0,1] \to \Omega$ with $\gamma_1(0) = \gamma_2(0)$ and $\gamma_1(1) = \gamma_2(1)$ we have the equality of the integrals

$$
\int_{\gamma_1} f(z) \textrm{ d}z = \int_{\gamma_2} f(z) \textrm{ d}z
$$

then we can pick a fixed point $p$ and for any $z$ pick a fixed path $\gamma_z$ from $p$ to $z$ and define

$$
F(z) = \int_{\gamma_z} f(w) \textrm{ d}w
$$

Then path independence ensures this is well-defined, and we have the theorem that $$F'(z) = f(z)$$.

To summarize the converse of the FTOC says "If a function on an open set is path independent, then it has a primitive".

This theorem is useful, for instance, to show that $\frac{1}{z}$ has a primitive (a "branch of the logarithm") defined on any simply connected open set which does not contain the origin.

**Cauchy's Theorem** says that if $f$ is holomorphic on a simply connected open set $\Omega$ and $\gamma:[0,1] \to \Omega$ is a closed path then

$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\textrm{ d}z = 0
$$

Note:  This has the consequence (from the converse to the Fundamental Theorem) that the $f$ is independent of path on this domain, which proves that holomorphic functions have primitives on simply connected domains.

We can use either Cauchy's theorem or the Fundamental Theorem to show that $\int_{C(0,1)} z \textrm{ d}z = 0$.  We can either use the fact that $z$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ or we can use the fact that $\frac{1}{2}z^2$ is an antiderivative.

Note that we **cannot** use Cauchy's theorem to conclude that $\int_{C(0,1)} \frac{1}{z^2} \textrm{ d}z = 0$ even though this is true by the Fundamental Theorem (or direct computation).

Finally

**Morera's Theorem** says that if $f$ is a continuous function on a simply connected open set $\Omega$ we have that

$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\textrm{ d}z = 0
$$

for **every** closed path $\gamma:[0,1] \to \Omega$, then $f$ is holomorphic.

This is a very useful theoretical tool.  The biggest use of this you will likely see in an introduction to complex analysis is to establish that uniform limits of holomorphic functions are holomorphic.

This can all be developed before the Cauchy Integral Formula.

Comment: Ok thank you, so am I correct in saying that this integral is zero?

Comment: @mosthigh Yes, you are correct.  I will add a little bit about how this idea fits in with the other major theorems of complex analysis.

Comment: Thanks that would be very helpful, I sometimes struggle when applying all the different theorems and can get confused on details

Answer (score 0):

Note
$$\int\left(1 - \frac{1}{z^2}\right)e^{z + 1/z}dz=\int e^{z + 1/z}d\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)=e^{z + 1/z}$$
and hence
$$\int_{S_1^+(0)}\left(1 - \frac{1}{z^2}\right)e^{z + 1/z}dz=e^{z + 1/z}\bigg|_{S_1^+(0)}=0.$$